# Problems with Python Modules

Tags: python, error-handling, module

So for some reason I am having problems with modules. I have projects I made lets say 4 monthes ago that I downloaded lets say openpyxl, or pyodbc. Now they dont work. For example I watched a video on requests a 2 weeks ago, everything worked great until about 30 minutes ago and now nothing does not recognize the module. I did

```
pip list
```

and all the pips i want are there but just wont work
I did uninstall python about a week ago because docx was not working, and it still wont. I updated the path. I am at a loss of what to do because projects I have worked on for weeks now just wont run because of the modules. Any suggestions? I mean its gotten to the point where I think i need someone to actually go through my computer and try to figure out the problem

Comment: Since you said you have uninstalled python and updated path . Here is what i would recommend you to check . Since Pip list is showing you all packages . 1) pip show <package_name> , here output will have location where packages are installed . Now check if this location matches with your python location .

Comment: okay, i found the problem for some reason, some pips where being installed in a different file, I dont know why or how to chnage that and I changed the path around and now it works

Comment: A clarification: You say "some pips where being installed in a different file". There is no such thing as "a pip". What you mean are packages or modules. `pip` is just the name of the program that installs those packages.

Comment: some packages where being installed in a different location so i had to find them and copy them over to the main path that I was using and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you did not install modules with pip2 instead of pip3 or vice versa? You cannot use modules from other versions of Python. Were you using a conda environment? Drive corruption? These all may be possible sources of your issue.

Comment: I would either do pip3 install or pip install. I for example right now uninstalled anaconda from my computer and still its not working. What weird that for example bs4 it show sin the code line that its recognized but when i run it says no module but when i do pip list it appears

Comment: Can you try installing conda, creating a new environment, entering the environment, and then install your pip packages?